# single positional indexer is out-of-bounds

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

```
with open('similarities/EuclideanSimilarity.csv', 'w') as result_file:

print('user1,user2,similarity', file=result_file)

print('Calculating similarities between users...')

for u1 in tqdm(users, total=len(users)):

for u2 in users:

ratings1 = np.nan_to_num(np.array(user_ratings_matrix.iloc[u1 - 1].values))

ratings2 = np.nan_to_num(np.array(user_ratings_matrix.iloc[u2 - 1].values))

              sim = 1 / (1 + distance.euclidean(ratings1, ratings2))
                print(f"{u1},{u2},{sim}", file=result_file)"
```

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in **getitem**(self, key)
   1371 
   1372             maybe_callable = com._apply_if_callable(key, self.obj)
-> 1373             return self._getitem_axis(maybe_callable, axis=axis)
   1374 
   1375     def _is_scalar_access(self, key):

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in _getitem_axis(self, key, axis)
   1828 
   1829             # validate the location
-> 1830             self._is_valid_integer(key, axis)
   1831 
   1832             return self._get_loc(key, axis=axis)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in _is_valid_integer(self, key, axis)
   1711         l = len(ax)
   1712         if key >= l or key < -l:
-> 1713             raise IndexError("single positional indexer is out-of-bounds")
   1714         return True
   1715

IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds

Comment: You're making us guess what the error is and where it occurs.  Please edit the question to include the full error trace message.

Comment: I don't know a lot about pandas or numpy, but I'm going to guess that `[u1 - 1]` is out of range for `user_ratings_matrix.iloc`.

Comment: Yes , I found the error that because I have 2113 users in the datasets but the userId is numbered randomly not 1,2,3,4 .....,2113. it is 75,78, ...,8567. so how can i fix this please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't give enough information about the type/contents of `users` or `user_ratings_matrix` to reliably answer your question. If I assume that `users` is a list of userIDs, and that `user_ratings_matrix` is a standard Pandas `DataFrame` *that is in the same order* as `users`, then you can rewrite your `for` loops as so:

```
for u1,row1 in tqdm(zip(users, user_ratings_matrix.itertuples(index=False, name=None)), total=len(users)):
    for u2,row2 in zip(users, user_ratings_matrix.itertuples(index=False, name=None)):
        ratings1 = np.nan_to_num(np.array(row1))
        ratings2 = np.nan_to_num(np.array(row2))
        sim = 1 / (1 + distance.euclidean(ratings1, ratings2))
        print(f"{u1},{u2},{sim}", file=result_file)"
```

#### Explanation

`user_ratings_matrix.itertuples(index=False, name=None)` will iterate over the rows in your dataframe and return each as a tuple.

`zip(users, user_ratings_matrix.itertuples(index=False, name=None))` will iterate over the pairs of `(userID, tuple(dataframe_row))`.

Also, before the next time you post a question on SO, you should probably read [these guidelines about how to produce an example that other people can run/work with](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It'll help you to get better answers on this site.